# Where do I get a JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, console

I am trying to teach myself JavaScript, and I am doing so by editing an existing program's files, but I would like to write a script, (not HTML) and run it, and see the console results to see what's going on instead of trying to get the output via odd ways.

Is there such a thing? I guess I am thinking like batch files where you can write one and then when it runs see what it is doing. I would also like to get console.log type output. Any ideas?

I am only interested in things like `2+2 = 4` – not trying to interface with anything.

I am just looking for a way to `console.log` my script. I am not looking for libraries or custom variants of JavaScript engines.

Is there really no way to make a pure JavaScript that says `2+2 =` and run it in a console window?

Comment: I don't know enough about it to make an answer, but I'd browse around [NODE.js](http://nodejs.org/) tools. They should have something.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly run JavaScript in a "normal" terminal, using a JavaScript interpreter.

V8 is Google's JavaScript engine, and you can download it from SVN, compile it, then run it in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion scons libreadline-dev
svn co http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk v8
cd v8/
scons console=readline d8
```

Building is also explained [on the Google Code page](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP). It comes with `d8`, a command-line JavaScript  interpreter.

Then all you need is to write a file, containing `print(2+2)`, and then run it through V8:

```
$ d8 /path/to/file.js
4
```

See also: [Sandeep's blog: Using the V8 javascript shell (D8)](http://www.sandeepdatta.com/2011/10/using-v8-javascript-shell-d8.html)

Comment: hey thanks, I found something called jsdb but I have not figured out how to run it yet. I will try yours here now

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has plugins that give you a JavaScript console to test with. You could run it on Linux.

*[Standalone JavaScript shells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Shells)*

Comment: I am a windows 8 user. will it still function, and will it run loops, I found jsfiddle, but it does the loops one at a time. edit: you did not mean use firefox or linux did you?

Comment: There is a few plugins you need to test them i suspect one of them will run loops but be warned be careful or infinite loops it will just about kill your computer and you need to do force restart with power button

Comment: Infinite loops in JavaScript will kill a computer? That's news to me.

Comment: I don't mean literally, i mean if the loop is bad it can cause the memory and cpu usage to hit 100% which can make it hard to kill manually as the whole computer goes slow

Comment: @AndrewCrawford - Just kill the Firefox process....A forced shutdown isn't required.

Comment: Either way, I would encourage you to provide more than just a link in your answer. A list of the most important points from the other page would be helpful in case the link breaks or changes.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes generally you can do that, but if CPU and Memory usage goes above 85% starting task manager to kill it can take about 5-10 minutes to load, and infinite loop can cause that sot of usage i know i have done it on windows and linux and linu is harde to do it on

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is intended to manipulate web documents. I don't see the point of trying to learn JavaScript without the web part. But it's an interesting method. Though its syntax is very related to [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), almost the only part that changes are the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) classes and names.

You may want to take a look at [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar. It allows you to have a live preview of HTML, [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and JavaScript and see how they work together right on your browser. Many people here uses it to show examples of code snippets and things like that.

**Update**:

Here is a [**cleaner version**](http://jsfiddle.net/5PQF9/4/) of [the fiddle in the comments](http://jsfiddle.net/5PQF9/) which may serve well for what you want, without having to install anything locally. Of course this wouldn't be the way to go if you want an off-line console.

You need to use a container to actually display the output of the JavaScript, like how I used the `Test` object.

```
Test.innerHTML += i + '<br/>';
```

This is the closest you can get to a console on JSFiddle.

Comment: thats what I am using now, but if I write a code that has loop in it, I have to click for each loop, I am not liking this because it causes me to have to make my loops smaller just to run the scripts, And I am learning this for the sake of learning it, and also to edit files in a program I already have, I have no desire to build web pages. Seems as if enough of thats going on LOL.

Comment: I don't get the part of having `to click for each loop`. A loop is a loop, JSFiddle doesn't stop loops every time they repeat.

Comment: Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VhYd8/76/), I didn't have to press the anchor everytime I wanted to print a number…

Comment: its funny you say that, because just as I came here to tell you guys I found a standalone http://www.jsdb.org/ that seems to do what I want, I also, realized the reason my loops are not working is that I put the -- on the wrong side, LOL. learning, its hard sometimes.

Comment: Your original question didn't mention you want a solution for databases in Javascript, but I'm glad you found something that fits your needs. By the way, you should do more research and code troubleshooting before asking a question.

Comment: database ? no I wanted an offline standalone program to run scripts through, if jsdb is a database program I am not using that function, two I can only ask what I what I know is a problem, I just now had the thought when I looked at my fiddle and was going to send it to you showing you that it would not run in fiddle, also, your fiddle was not pure javascript, it has some other code in it that allowed you to display on the side bar, I think that would be perfect for my needs to use fiddle but I have to figure out it is you did that did that. I do appreciate all the help. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: @Donald I didn't use any special code (other than specifying that the javascript is put in the header of the document), I used an existent template though, that's why you may be seeing jquery or something else I think in the run configurations. And your code wasn't properly debugged or revised at the moment you published the question, you can ask whatever you want, but for the *sake of the community*, please ask properly formulated and well documented questions.

Comment: @Donald Here is a [cleaned up version](http://jsfiddle.net/5PQF9/) of the former fiddle. As you can see I only set the script to be added to the `head` of the document rather than on `onLoad` (which is what one would normally do). And regarding jsdb, how can you claim you found what you were looking for if you didn't even notice it is a database access module?

Comment: again, I am doing the best I can, I formatted and asked the question as I understood it, when I understood it, for the reasons I understood it. I can my no pretense to assume that my question is not in a format that or researched correctly to someones else understanding if I myself am having and issue understanding or identifying the issue as it exists. I do the best I can with the knowledge and understanding I have at this time. considering I have never even seen javascript until two weeks ago and am teaching my self, I feel I am doing pretty good. Again, thanks for all the assistance.

Comment: Check my updated answer, it may be the most close you can get to a console with jsfiddle.

Comment: @arielnmz It's taken a while, but Javascript has escaped the browser. [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) is probably the best known use now. XUL + Javascript can make local apps, or Mozilla phone apps.

Comment: so after looking at your fiddle i made my own, I figure I can write a few extra lines to compensate for what wont run in my program for what will and get the results you are getting http://jsfiddle.net/OldGuyGamer/5PQF9/5/ ps. how did you change your links name

Comment: Check [this updated](http://jsfiddle.net/5PQF9/6/) version of your fiddle, where you give input to the `Say` function and prints it to the div. And as for the links, check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments). The sintax is: [ name of the link ] ( url of the link ).

Comment: @RichHomolka but if NodeJS is intended to run on the server, how can it replace javascript, which runs on the client?

Comment: @arielnmz It's a Javascript based server. Javascript is just a language. It is not tied to a web browser by anything other than convention and speed. Modern Javascript engines make it fast enough for server use. It doesn't replace any client use, it's just a different way to code a server.

Comment: @RichHomolka well, you said that *NodeJS is probably the best known use now*, so I thought you meant it as a replacement for javascript. It may be a solution for what the op wants though. In this case, would it be a replacement for PHP right?

Answer (score 0):

Check out NodeJS, it allows you to run JavaScript outside of a browser. You can also use [Nacre.sh](https://nacre.sh), which is a JavaScript Shell based on NodeJS that provides a set of practical functions such as `ls`, `cd`, `chmod`, etc.

Here are some examples:

```js
> 1 + 1
2
```

```js
> [1, 2, 3, 4].map(e => e * e)
[ 1, 4, 9, 16 ]
```

```js
> ls()
[
  'Applications',
  'Desktop',
  'Documents',
  'Downloads',
  'Library',
  'Movies',
  'Music',
  'Pictures'
]
```

Let's say you want to run the following JS script:

```js
// myscript.js
const you = 'World!';
console.log('Hello', you);
```

```bsh
# use nacre or node depending on if you want the bash ls, cd, etc. functions
nacre ./myscript.js 
Hello World!
```